# Updating user information for an extend user field - Django

Tags: django, profile, updating

I'm trying to create an update_profile form. This form will be able to 
update extended user information that is not in the original form. 
So, I have a form that allows you to create an account. There a lot of 
other fields that aren't listed in this form. The rest of these fields 
will be found when the user actually logs in and attempts to edit their profile. What I can't figure out 
is how to make the save function in that class that allows them to update this information. 
Like in the extended user class that I made, I have a save function 
that creates a user and saves it. But I don't want to create another 
user with this form. I simply want to update the current authenticated 
user. I thought there would be an update_user-type function in the 
UserManager(), but there isn't. I tried googling and didn't come up 
with much. Help Please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ModelForm` to create a form to your custom `UserProfile` model with a [subset of the fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form):

> **Using a subset of fields on the form**
>
> > In some cases, you may not want all
> >     the model fields to appear on the
> >     generated form. There are three ways
> >     of telling ModelForm to use only a
> >     subset of the model fields:
>
> 1. Set editable=False on the model field.
>      As a result, any form created from the
>      model via ModelForm will not include
>      that field.
> 2. Use the fields attribute
>      of the ModelForm's inner Meta class.
>      This attribute, if given, should be a
>      list of field names to include in the
>      form. The order in which the fields
>      names are specified in that list is
>      respected when the form renders them.
> 3. Use the exclude attribute of the
>      ModelForm's inner Meta class. This
>      attribute, if given, should be a list
>      of field names to exclude from the
>      form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form

Comment: I understand how to exclude certain categories and make the form my own, but I'm not quite asking this. Let me try explaining better, if I make a form in HTML, i can set a "value" parameter. I want this value for every form field to be set to the values in the database. Then, when the user changes the values and resubmits, it updates this information. Help me please, thank you.

Comment: In your view, use `form = MyForm(instance=myinstance)` to load your values.  Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/